# blank in regular expression in flex

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

I have the following regular expression in a flex file. (.l file)

```
  doctype [[:blank:] \r\n]*<!DOCTYPE[^\[]*\[[[:blank:] \r\n]*
```

From a flex tutorial, in the `pattern` chapiter, I saw that `flex defines ‘[:blank:]’ as a blank or a tab.`

But in the expression above, why do we need another blank after `[:blank:]`?

Comment: You do not need it, you can remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[:blank:]` POSIX character class matches a space or a tab (even in the [FLEX patterns manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html)).

Thus, the `[[:blank:] \r\n]`  character class equals `[[:blank:]\r\n]`.

Same as `[rr]` = `[r]`.

Comment: Note, I used *character class* (not *bracket expression*) term since the regex flavor here is actually not POSIX, a `.` matches any symbol but a newline in Flex regex.